# custom module event redirecting to cart page not next checkout steps

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout, billing

I'm trying to add custom field in my magento checkout billing

but my module event ..

**controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling**

not proceeding to next step ... is there any solution for this....

```
public function saveBilling(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {

        $fieldVal = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('billing');
        Mage::log('My 1st log entry'.print_r($fieldVal,true), null, 'system.log');
        $observer->getOrder()->setCustomerNote((string)$fieldVal[customer_note]);    

    }
```

i try log Request->Params results in my events observer methods and it log my billing data... what should i do make it work

**I'm trying to save a field data when customer saves billing information**

Comment: most probably, the `saveBilling` call response does not return a valid JSON.

Comment: How to know saveBilling return a valid JSON or not

Comment: use firebug for firefox or the developer tools for chrome to see the ajax call response.

Comment: i get this error <b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function setCustomerNote() on a non-object in <b>/home/thesolarbiz
/public_html/app/code/local/Brightnote/Comment/Model/Observer.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br />

Comment: Post the code from that file in the question